# Weighted dirac comb supported on a uniform discret set a tempered distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I want to prove the following statement.
Let $$\mu=\sum\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mu(\lambda)\delta_{\lambda},\mu(\lambda)\neq0$$ a measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\Lambda$ a uniform discrete set.
Then $\mu$ is a temperate distribution if and only if $$|\mu(\lambda)|\leq C(1+|\lambda|^{N}),\lambda\in\Lambda$$
for some positive Constants $C$ and $N$.

I managed to solve the $\leftarrow$ direction. For the other direction my thought was something to try with $|\mu(\lambda)|>C(1+|\lambda|^{N})$ . Because then $|\mu(\lambda)|$ would be grow faster then a polynomial and then the sum would be infinite but I'm not sure how to write that down.

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I did $\rightarrow$ direction. And for the other i thought one way would be to assume the $|\mu(\lambda)|>C(1+|\lambda|^{N})$ but then i stucked.

Comment: Do you mind adding that into your question? Along with your thoughts on that approach? That would prevent your question from being closed.